# Run a function periodically in background mode in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to make an api call to backend when the app is in background (closed) mode in react native.
Basically, the function should check for internet connection and then get some data from async storage , then make an api call to sync the data with the db.
I'm not familiar with native code.

Can anyone help me with how this can be achieved ? Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make API calls in the background for iOS devices as Apple Policy restrict developer to run tasks in background iOS.

So, If you are looking to make API calls in the background for Android devices.

Then you can use the below dependency to run API calls in the background.

[React Native Background Fetch](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-fetch)